# How can I submit a visionOS app with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, visionos

I have an iOS app which runs fine on visionOS simulator and I have added the visionOS target to my app record in App Store Connect.

But, I do not see any means to archive and submit my visionOS binary in Xcode?

Any hints on this?

Comment: You should be able to submit via the Organizer like other apps. However when I try to submit mine, it says that my account does not have access to xrOS yet and my account needs to be updated. But my account page shows no updates available.

Comment: The problem is how to generate the archive ? I don't want a native vision app, but a "designed for iPad" one. I can select visionos simulator to run my iOS app which works fine, but HOW do I generate the archive for the visionos app ? I don't see any means in Xcode to build my app other than for "iOS"...

Comment: Oh, try this, in Xcode go to the project window. In the left column under Project & Targets, click the + at the bottom of the column and select visionOS as the target type, fill in the details etc.

Comment: Is that possible at this point? Apple would have provided docs for this use case, I'd assume.

Comment: fwiw; I am now able to submit apps for visionOS. However, iPad apps will be available in the visionOS store automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

In Apple docs it is stated that "visionOS (designed for iPad)" is made available automatically (if you have opted-in). Only for native visionOS app you need to add a target in Xcode and add the platform in AppStore Connect.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add target, just a supported destination in your app target. Remove visionOS (design for iPad) if necessary and add "visionOS". (ref: [Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/bringing-your-app-to-visionos))

Next, select "any visionOS device" before building and you will have the visionOS variant. No need to change bundle ID in this case!

Here the result for my app iSoft:
[image: iSoft vision OS]